# Try - Catch - End Try Usage

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

Should I rather use

```
Try 
   'Blabla
Catch
   'Do nothing if error occurs
End try
```

Or should I use

```
Try
   'Blabla
Catch : End Try
```

Whats the difference between those two?

Comment: There is no difference. Only that they both swallow exceptions-Not a difference, is it?

Comment: You should not be hiding exceptions by catching them and then ignoring them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference.

The first example is used if you want something to happen when an error occurs. However, it is better practice to use the second one if your not going to run any code in case of an exception

Answer (score 3):

Call me "Old Fashioned" but it's probably better to use the first approach and actually do something with the exception.

Comment: You don't have to have a catch at all but then you need a Finally. Clean up unmanaged resources. Up vote for no empty catch.

Comment: @Mary If you have unmanaged resources, I'd recommend to wrap them in a class that implements `IDisposable` and then use `Using` to automate cleanup, instead of having to remember to manually institute the cleanup in `Finally` blocks every place you use them (and remember to update all of the instances when something about the cleanup procedure changes).